# How to spawn obstacles when level increase?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, spawn

I have one question I want to spawn different obstacles when player proceed to next levels, I have infinite number of levels and I want to spawn sometime a random obstacles, my obstacles are into prefabs. Everything works with spawn but when I do it on my way the code goes too much, because there will be more then 500 lines for 200 levels, as I check if the level is higher then 0 and lower then 10 to spawn obstacles for only 10 levels, then next will be another same code to check else if levels are more then 10 and smaller then 20.. Also I want to spawn random obstacles on level from 1-10 so my code gets bigger again.

This is simple code for first 10 levels:

```
 if(currentLevel>0 && currentLevel < 10{

        for (int i = 0; i < objectNumberSpawner; i++)
        {
            int randomCircleSpawner = Random.Range(0, 3);

            switch (randomCircleSpawner)
            {
                case 0:
                    Debug.Log("this");
                    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[0], new Vector3(obstacles[0].transform.position.x, obstacles[0].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);

                    startSpawn += deltaY;
                    spawnPlane();

                    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[1], new Vector3(obstacles[1].transform.position.x, obstacles[1].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);
                    startSpawn += deltaY;
                    spawnPlane();

                    break;

                case 1:
                    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[1], new Vector3(obstacles[1].transform.position.x, obstacles[1].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);

                    startSpawn += deltaY;
                    spawnPlane();
                    break;


                case 2:
                    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[2], new Vector3(obstacles[2].transform.position.x, obstacles[2].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);
                    startSpawn += deltaY;
                    spawnPlane();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[3], new Vector3(obstacles[3].transform.position.x, obstacles[3].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);
                    startSpawn += deltaY;
                    spawnPlane();
                    break;

            }
        }
    }else if (currentLevel)
    {

    }
```

My question is is there any other way to spawn different obstacles with different prefabs when player reaches some levels, because this is too much of code , but if that is the only way i think i need to proceed.. in code sample else if is not made but there goes same process for higher levels with only more obstacles.. I don't know is this proper way because there will be more then 1000 lines of codes for levels and that doesn't make sense for me.

When I add the nearly same process to spawn powerups on that levels that will be crazy how much lines of code I will have..

Thank you stackoverflow for pointing me out to right solution because that will not be good as i guess.

Edit: I forget to mention that when level increases the objects in switch statement under variable "lastObjectCreated " will change too .. I hope someone has better solution then mine..

Comment: I lack understanding what *specific* requirements on spawning there are, so my answer is incomplete. But I hope it's helpful. Ping me (@trollingchar) if you add these requirements to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, I see that your `switch` block can be shortened drastically. Let's see:

```
case 2:
    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[2], new Vector3(obstacles[2].transform.position.x, obstacles[2].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);
    startSpawn += deltaY;
    spawnPlane();
    break;
case 3:
    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[3], new Vector3(obstacles[3].transform.position.x, obstacles[3].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);
    startSpawn += deltaY;
    spawnPlane();
    break;
```

Almost identical. Let's declare a local function and pass an index as a parameter:

```
void SpawnObstacle (int i) {
    lastObjectCreated = Instantiate(obstacles[i], new Vector3(obstacles[i].transform.position.x, obstacles[i].transform.position.y, startSpawn), Quaternion.identity);
    startSpawn += deltaY;
    spawnPlane();
}
```

And our entire `switch` becomes:

```
switch (randomCircleSpawner) {
    case 0:
        SpawnObstacle (0);
        SpawnObstacle (1);
        break;
    case 1:
        SpawnObstacle (1);
        break;
    case 2:
        SpawnObstacle (2);
        break;
    case 3:
        SpawnObstacle (3);
        break;
}
```

Simplifying it even more:

```
SpawnObstacle (randomCircleSpawner);
if (randomCircleSpawner == 0) {
    SpawnObstacle (1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't think about this, now my code is really much smaller.. I need to spawn powerups more..